# ElasticSearch and JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, elasticsearch, environment-variables

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch. I'm trying to add JAVA_HOME to Environment variables. I added JAVA_HOME  like this : 
[image]

But when I run elasticsearch : I get this :

```
C:\elastic\bin>elasticsearch
JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can you tell me how I can get elastic search running? Thanks.

Comment: It may be having a problem because there's a space in the path between "Program" and "Files".  Try putting double quotes around it: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"

Comment: @duffymo I did what you said but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If you open a command shell and type "set JAVA_HOME", what does it say?

Comment: @duffymo it says "JAVA_HOME". Thank you

Comment: @duffymo Sorry it says this : "JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"

Comment: It should tell you what it thinks the value is.  That might be your problem.  Mine says "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77" in the command shell when I type "set JAVA_HOME".  You didn't do it correctly.

Comment: @duffymo I posted another reply, please read it.

Comment: I saw it.  Open the script you're using to start elastic search and see what it's problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name. For example: `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`

Comment: downvoted because this way you can't differentiate between "Program files x86" and "Program Files"

Answer (score -1):

Is your java path set properly? Try with "java -version" command in cmd and check the result.

Comment: I get this when I write that command : 
`java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

Comment: Can you please show me the content of "elasticsearch.in" file which resides in "Your_Elastic_Search_Installation_Directory\bin" ?

Answer (score -1):

In order to set Environment variables (in windows): 
 Click rigth in this pc > properties
 Advanced system settings 
 Environment Variables
Set your JAVA_HOME with his path and click ok